# Caching and searching API responses for multiple requests

Tags: python, graphql

I am working with an graphQL API that is rate limited but also allows for large responses. This is an example of a single operation:

Given some search term by a user "Nike Pegasus Running Shoes", I can query this API and get a response json of a couple thousand results. Now what I want to do with this response is sort or search the entries such that I can take the most similar results from that response (across title, category, etc). I also want to save this response so that if two queries are similar, I can re-use the response. Should I be setting up a SQL database for this and storing the responses in there?

I would appreciate some advice on what database or stack I should be using to build for this. As this operation needs to be done thousands of times, caching responses locally isn't ideal. Currently the rest of the code for this project is written in Python if that helps.

```
{
       "title": "Nike Pegasus 35",
      "description": "Category: Shoes. Sub-category: Sneakers. Brand: Nike.  Material: Flyknit. Color: blue. Size: 10.5 US",
      "category": "Men > SHOES > SNEAKERS",
      "price": {
            "amount": "120",
            "currency": "USD"
               },

       "URL": "https://www.nike.com/products/x"
               
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "caching responses locally isn't ideal" because isn't that your question? Anyway, for caching my thought is to use Redis, simpler to manage than a SQL DB, it's not going to break a sweat on any amount of data you put in or take out, and it has the convenient option to discard data after some amount of time. Google the "Little Redis Book" to see what it has to offer

Comment: Appreciate the pointer on Redis, will take a look. Well I am more looking for any solution that would work for this kind of problem, what I had thought of initially was caching the responses locally but that does not seem like the best way to handle the data.

Comment: That is what I meant though, caching the responses locally in Redis (or anything else). Is it deciding "if two queries are similar" that you want to solve? Because then I misunderstood it entirely :)

Comment: Appreciate the discourse, maybe I was not clear enough in the question as well! I need to store the responses somewhere and also determine whether or not a query is similar enough to reuse the data. I think I can resolve the similarity with queries by parsing each query to check what the main attributes of the query are.